# Parsing multiple *.csv with ISO 8601 timestamp and custom tick

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy, matplotlib

I am post-processing output data *.csv files and feel like using Python3.7/Numpy/Matplotlib.

Datas are minute-log-rotate-filenames:

```
POWER_2018-08-19T00:56.csv 
POWER_2018-08-19T00:57.csv
POWER_2018-08-19T00:58.csv
TEMP_2018-08-19T00:56.csv
TEMP_2018-08-19T00:57.csv
TEMP_2018-08-19T00:58.csv
```

With the following structure (no header, example from "POWER_*.csv" content):

> 2018-08-19T00:57:23.166;11.991;0.298;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:26.170;11.991;0.298;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:29.175;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:32.177;11.992;0.300;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:35.181;11.991;0.298;27.990;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:38.185;11.991;0.300;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:41.189;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:44.193;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:47.197;11.991;0.301;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:50.206;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:53.209;11.991;0.298;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:56.213;11.992;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:57:59.217;11.991;0.299;27.990;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:58:02.222;11.991;0.299;27.992;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:58:05.226;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:58:08.229;11.991;0.299;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:58:11.233;11.991;0.298;27.991;0.691;
>   2018-08-19T00:58:14.237;11.992;0.299;27.991;0.691;

So I am parsing these with the following MCV example:

```
import glob
import dateutil
import datetime
import numpy as np

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('/windows/data/2018-08-19T00:57/POWER*.csv'))

for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    df = np.genfromtxt(f, names=['Timestamp', 'Volt1', 'Curr1', 'Volt2', 'Curr2'], delimiter=';',converters={0:dateutil.parser.parse},dtype=[datetime.datetime, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float])
    print(df)
    data = np.concatenate(df)

print(data)
```

This is returning me:

```
./parse_csv.py                                                             420ms  Thu 23 Aug 2018 06:06:00 PM CEST
/windows/data/2018-08-19T00:57/POWER_2018-08-19T00:57.csv
[(datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 5, 132000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 8, 145000), 11.991, 0.3  , 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 11, 150000), 11.991, 0.3  , 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 14, 153000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 17, 157000), 11.992, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 20, 162000), 11.992, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 23, 166000), 11.991, 0.298, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 26, 170000), 11.991, 0.298, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 29, 175000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 32, 177000), 11.992, 0.3  , 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 35, 181000), 11.991, 0.298, 27.99 , 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 38, 185000), 11.991, 0.3  , 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 41, 189000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 44, 193000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 47, 197000), 11.991, 0.301, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 50, 206000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 53, 209000), 11.991, 0.298, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 56, 213000), 11.992, 0.299, 27.991, 0.691)
 (datetime.datetime(2018, 8, 19, 0, 57, 59, 217000), 11.991, 0.299, 27.99 , 0.691)]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse_csv.py", line 27, in <module>
    data = np.concatenate(df)
ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

Which is puzzling me for the following reasons/questions:
a.) the concatenation is not working anymore after I introduced the converters in order to fight with the datetime format conversion back to datetime. What is the best way to parse multiple (relevant  & similar) cvs files? would pandas be of any help here? is it really bad practice to use different csv inputs?
b.) I would like to plot all the non-timestamp values (4 here) in Y-axis against the timestamp (X), but these are not regularly sampled: How shall I strech my timestamp/values in a real timeline ? use of padding for missing value? is the custom tick the answer?

Thank you for your hints !

Comment: `df` from `genfromtxt` is a 1d array with multiple fields (a structured array).  It doesn't make any sense to apply `concatenate` to it.  Are you trying to change that array specifically, or are you trying to collect multiple `df` (from multiple files) into one array?

Comment: Yes, exactly: trying to collect multiple df (from multiple files) into one array (indeed, above code is not working, had to introduce an ugly `firstRun=True/False` in order to initialize `data` with the first `df`...I guess/hope there is a more pythonic way...

Comment: The preferred style is to collect the arrays in a list, and do one concatenate at the end. Co concatenate  along the way is messier to initialize, and slower.

Comment: It may simplify matters for you if you convert the datetime object to an epoch time. Then you can hold everything in arrays with dtype=float. If d1 is a datetime object, time.mktime(d1.timetuple()) + d1.microsecond*1e-6 is a float holding seconds and microseconds since the epoch.

Comment: `np.datetime64` is handy, though it can be a bit tricky to use.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `pandas` for working with timeseries. It is nearly a one-liner (well, in fact it is a two-liner...) to load csv data and concatenate the files:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame()
for f in filenames:
    print(f)
    df = pd.read_csv(
        f, sep=';', index_col=0, header=None,
        parse_dates=True, infer_datetime_format=True)
    print(df)
    data = pd.concat((data, df), axis=0)
```

`pandas` stores the data internally as `np.ndarray`. So if you want to have your data in this format, you can get the data with `data_as_ndarray = df.values`.

If you have multiple csv files with different data in the columns, like power in one set of files and temperature in another set of files, I recommend loading each set of files into a separate and then afterwards concatenating the resulting dataframes with:

```
df_total = pd.concat((df_total_power, df_total_temp), axis=1)
```

If your multiple csv files are not fully ordered in time, you should sort you data by the index after concatenating:

```
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

`np.nan` from concatenating two files with different timestamps can then be filled with:

```
df_total = df_total.interpolate()
```

With pandas you can also plot irregularly spaced timeseries. Just call `data.plot.line()`. But of course you can resample the data to evenly spaced data for example to 10 miliseconds with

```
data = data.resample('10ms').mean().interpolate()
```

This will take the mean value for downsampling (if any) and interpolate the `np.nan` for upsampling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution where the concatenation is performed at the end:

```
import numpy as np
import glob
import dateutil
import datetime

filenames = sorted(glob.glob('./csvdata/power*.csv'))

data = [np.genfromtxt(f, names=['Timestamp', 'Volt1', 'Curr1', 'Volt2', 'Curr2'],
                  delimiter=';',
                  converters={0:dateutil.parser.parse},
                  dtype=[datetime.datetime, np.float, np.float, np.float, np.float])
        for f in filenames]

data = np.concatenate(data)
print(data.shape)  # (18,)
```